# Logging of C# console app - How to add summary overall on the top of txt log file(instead of bottom)

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, serilog

I develop console app that will parse excel file with 1000 rows. I need to trace each row and finally I need to add summary overall on the top of txt log file.

I'm going to use Serilog or Nlog.

What is the most efficient way to add summary overall **on the top** of log file?(Not bottom)

The log file should be like:

[image]

Comment: This will require the entire file to be rewritten.

Comment: Read all text, then write it back with your prefix. Seems no other way

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in Serilog that would give you that. Moreover, **that is not a log file**... **It's a report**.

Write your logs to a place that you can easily query later, and write a script or app that can query the logs and generate the report that you need.

You can find the [main Serilog sinks in the Serilog GitHub organization](https://github.com/serilog?q=-sinks-&type=&language=) (search for `-sinks-`) and in the wiki there's a [list of community-provided Serilog sinks](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks) that you give you ideas of possible storage you can use... Can be text file, database, and others.